# Enabling impersonation and use Powershell as admin role

Tags: powershell, admin, impersonation, exchangewebservices

I am making an application that uses the EWS API, this application accesses different accounts, and in order to do that I have to use the impersonation. I have tried the impersonation ... but the problem I receive the error that I do not have permissions for impersonations. So I tried to modify the exchange server to add the ability to impersonate, but when I tried to follow some commands like which are given by MSDN

```
New-ManagementRoleAssignment -Name <impersonationAssigmentName> -Role applicationImpersonation -User <serviceAccount>
```

but I get this error

```
The term 'New-ManagementRoleAssignment' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
```

According to my friend that this might be the problem of not using the exchange server using the Admin, but I am logging to the windows serving using the admin account. 
Honestly I am totally new to Exchange Server, this I need to solve this admin thing hopefully it will solve my problem .

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Exchange tools loaded locally? You'll need those tools in order to call the cmdlets.

Alternatively, use remoting and open a pssession to your Exchange server and try running the cmdlets in the remote session.